# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField 1:N initial

Tags: python, django

I have two Models, Machine and Device

```py
class Machine(models.Model):
    pass

class Device(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, related_name='devices')
```

Now in Django Admin, In Machine change page, I want to be able to add 1-N Device references, it works nice and out of the box with ManyToMany relation, here is how it looks in admin (desired)
[image]

I am trying to use `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` for 1:N selection. I've already figured out saving of this relation, but feeding the initial value just doesnt seem to work.

How I am trying to feed initial values:

```py
class MachineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Machine
        fields = '__all__'

    devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Device.objects.filter(machine=None).all(), required=False) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MachineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['devices'].initial = self.instance.devices.all()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(MachineForm, self).save(commit=False)
        self.fields['devices'].initial.update(machine=None)
        instance.save()
        self.cleaned_data['devices'].update(machine=instance)
        return instance
```

In debugger, I can clearly that the initial queryset is nonempty:

`initial <QuerySet [<Device: 10126>, <Device: 10127>]>`
 but the field in django admin is still empty.

[image]

Anyone knows why?

EDIT:

I've already tried

`self.fields['devices'].initial = self.instance.devices.all().values_list('id', flat=True)`

with no luck.

EDIT2:

Debug Log from `self.fields['devices'].__dict__`

```
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] empty_label -> None
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] required -> False
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] label -> None
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] initial -> <QuerySet [<Device: 10126>, <Device: 10127>]>
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] show_hidden_initial -> False
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] help_text -> 
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] disabled -> False
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] label_suffix -> None
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] localize -> False
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] widget -> <django.forms.widgets.SelectMultiple object at 0x7f7d749597f0>
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] error_messages -> {'required': 'This field is required.', 'invalid_choice': 'Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the available choices.', 'list': 'Enter a list of values.', 'invalid_pk_value': '"%(pk)s" is not a valid value.'}
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] validators -> []
[api-857c7fc84d-rh42v api-app] _queryset -> <QuerySet [<Device: 10036>, <Device: 10135>, <Device: 10062>, <Device: 10069>, <Device: 10101>, <Device: 10139>, <Device: 10022>, <Device: 10149>, <Device: 10103>, <Device: 10146>, <Device: 10020>, <Device: 10040>, <Device: 10075>, <Device: 10123>, <Device: 10059>, <Device: 10001>, <Device: 10142>, <Device: 10148>, <Device: 10097>, <Device: 10118>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Widget as dict:

```
[api-66c9c5d85c-qtnrq api-app] attrs -> {}
[api-66c9c5d85c-qtnrq api-app] choices -> <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceIterator object at 0x7f6c73ad4ac8>
[api-66c9c5d85c-qtnrq api-app] is_required -> False
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the IDs? `self.fields['devices'].initial = self.instance.devices.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Unfortunately no, forgot to mention that I've tried this already, I just cant understand why it is ignoring the initial set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. After looking for hours into `Django` Documentation I've found this in `ModelMultipleChoiceField` source code.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/models/#ModelMultipleChoiceField

```py
def _check_values(self, value):
        """
        Given a list of possible PK values, return a QuerySet of the
        corresponding objects. Raise a ValidationError if a given value is
        invalid (not a valid PK, not in the queryset, etc.) <- NOT IN THE QUERYSET?!
        """
        key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
        # deduplicate given values to avoid creating many querysets or
        # requiring the database backend deduplicate efficiently.
        try:
            value = frozenset(value)
        except TypeError:
            # list of lists isn't hashable, for example
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['list'],
                code='list',
            )
        for pk in value:
            try:
                self.queryset.filter(**{key: pk}) # <------
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                raise ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_pk_value'],
                    code='invalid_pk_value',
                    params={'pk': pk},
                )
        qs = self.queryset.filter(**{'%s__in' % key: value})
        pks = {str(getattr(o, key)) for o in qs}
        for val in value:
            if str(val) not in pks:
                raise ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_choice'],
                    code='invalid_choice',
                    params={'value': val},
                )
        return qs
```

Problem was that my initial and my queryset were in disjunction, thus it was failing silently somewhere.

So chaning

```
devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Device.objects.filter(machine=None).all(), required=False)
```

to

```
devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Device.objects.all(), required=False)
```

fixed the problem.

I am wondering if this is a bug in `Django`? Since initial values are always going to be missing in queryset, atleast in my case, as my queryset is collection of unassigned devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the choices as tuple, in order to convert the resultant query into tuple you'll have to do something like below and it will work:

```
CHOICES = tuple((x.id, x.devices) for x in Device.objects.all())


class MachineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    devices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Machine
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I am not having troubles with the queryset, that works fine, I am having problems with initial values. And even if I pass it as tuples it does not work, so this does not answers my question unfortunately, addionaly, `x.devices` does not make any sense as x is Device object

Comment: Also I am using `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, not `MultipleChoiceField`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it. In case of ModelMultipleChoiceField you can just use `devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Device.objects.all())` you don't have to type 'queryset='

Comment: Queryset is the list of possible choices, that is fine, I cant fill the initial, that means, already selected objects are not visible.

Comment: `form = MachineForm(initial={'abc': Device.objects.filter(pk=2)})` marks the options as selected, you can find that out by inspecting the element. But it isn't shown in the browser as selected, one work around for this can be using some css styling like: `select[multiple] option[selected] { background: blue; color: white; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `queryset` property instead:

```
if self.instance:
        self.fields['devices'].queryset = self.instance.devices.all()
```

Comment: Hello, If I do this, then not only the inital is still empty, but the queryset of devices that i can choose is only limited to two (The initial queryset). So, initial != queryset, as stated before.